# Sequence Stack and structure pointer

Tags: c

I want to write a binary tree traversal algorithm, to push the structure pointer of the binary tree node in the sequence stack, but when I apply for memory, I have a problem, that is, `S->data = (tNode*)malloc(sizeof(tNode ) * maxSize);` This sentence has a problem, every time the debugging is stopped in this block. But I don\'t know what the correct solution is and ask for answers.

```
typedef struct TreeNode {
    char data;
    struct TreeNode *left;
    struct TreeNode *right;
} TreeNode, *tNode;

typedef struct sNode {
    tNode* data;
    int top;
    int maxSize;
} sNode, *Stack;

Status createStack(Stack S,int maxSize) {
    S->data = (tNode*) malloc(sizeof(tNode) *maxSize);
    S->top = -1;
    S->maxSize = maxSize;
    return OK;
}
```

Comment: How do you call `createStack`?

Comment: Try `sizeof(struct sNode)` instead of `sizeof(tNode)`.
Ps. this is strange style define structure - `}TreeNode,*tNode;`

Comment: can you show us the error messages?

Answer (score 0):

`tnode` is a type of a pointer to a structure

So, when you use

```
S->data = (tNode*)malloc(sizeof(tNode ) * maxSize);
```

you are typecasting with `(tnode*)` you are using a pointer to pointer to structure. Also the size of the allocated memory will be the size of the pointer, not the size of the structure. In addition you should not typecast the result of your malloc calls.

The typedef for your `Stack` is also using a pointer to pointer of structure. I guess this is not what you want for your application.

You should use

```
typedef struct sNode {
    TreeNode* data;
    int top;
    int maxSize;
} sNode, *Stack;
```

Then you can allocate memory as

```
S->data = malloc(sizeof(TreeNode) * maxsize);
```